# How send file to ftp server to the same name?

Tags: bash

I have the code to find the last modified file and send to a ftp server but the name is not the same. How can I send file to ftp to the same name?

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(find /home/local/server/ -mmin -120 -name '*.csv.gz')
hostname="192.168.5.11"
username="user"
password="pass"
echo "Send file $filename to the server $hostname"

ftp -n $hostname <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
passive
ascii

put $filename /home/remote/server/file_name_found_on_local_server
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Have you considered what will happen if `find /home/local/server/ ...` returns more than one file? Looks like a genuine "bad thing" waiting to happen...

Comment: @twalberg too true. In that case why not use `-exec sh -c ...` to do it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the `basename` of the `$filename`. Then use that as you put the file.

```
file=$(basename $filename)
```

then

```
put $filename /home/remote/server/$file
```

By the way you have a gzip'ed file that you are using ascii mode for. I would replace `ascii` with `bin`.